# Android Play Sound even if Media Volume is 0

Tags: android, media, volume, audiotrack

I want to play music with AudioTrack even if the media volume of the device is 0. 
In my app, I want to have a SeekBar for the media volume (maybe if other music runs in the background) and one other SeekBar for the music of my app.

Until now, I can change the media volume. But then the music of my app is also silent..

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know if you can distinguish media volumes like this. Pretty sure there isn't Application specific volume control by default with the OS. You could attempt to track application streams or something, but it would be hard to cover all of your cases.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to ignore the users set volume preferences.  I don't think this is a good UX decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

Now I use "AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, (...))" and it's working good.
Maybe it's not the best method but by now, it's working.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is Six Different Streams of Sound in Android for Playing Different Types of Sounds

The first step to creating a predictable audio experience is understanding which audio stream your app will use.

Android maintains a separate audio stream for playing 
***music, 
alarms,
notifications, 
the incoming call ringer, 
system sounds,
in-call volume,
and DTMF tones.***
 This is done primarily to allow users to control the volume of each stream independently.

> **Use Hardware Volume Keys to Control Your App’s Audio Volume**

By default, pressing the volume controls modify the volume of the active audio stream. If your app isn't currently playing anything, hitting the volume keys adjusts the ringer volume.

If you've got a game or music app, then chances are good that when the user hits the volume keys they want to control the volume of the game or music, even if they’re currently between songs or there’s no music in the current game location.

You may be tempted to try and listen for volume key presses and modify the volume of your audio stream that way. Resist the urge. Android provides the handy setVolumeControlStream() method to direct volume key presses to the audio stream you specify.

Having identified the audio stream your application will be using, you should set it as the volume stream target. You should make this call early in your app’s lifecycle—because you only need to call it once during the activity lifecycle, you should typically call it within the onCreate() method (of the Activity or Fragment that controls your media). This ensures that whenever your app is visible, the volume controls function as the user expects.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

From this point onwards, pressing the volume keys on the device affect the audio stream you specify (in this case “music”) whenever the target activity or fragment is visible.

Comment: This is a far better answer than my comment. The only problem I see possibly arising is if a stream you want to silence coincides with a stream you want to turn up or something. For example, could you not have a two different audio tracks running on your "music" stream?